# Feature files called on after scenario hooks would not print to html report

Tags: karate

I am following the demo for after scenario hooks that supposedly enable us to print to html file by calling a feature file (https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/4e4583390f28891665033607ace88272f4ab6aff)

Below is my config.

- karate-config.js

  `karate.configure('afterScenario', read('classpath:hooks.js'));`
- hooks.js

```
    function(){
        var response = karate.get('response');
        karate.log(response);
        if(response.errors!=null)
        karate.call('classpath:features/Utils/AfterScenario.feature', { respond: response });
      }
```

- AfterScenario.feature

```
    @ignore
    Feature: To print response after scenario hook

    Scenario:
    * print 'RESPONSE ==> ', respond
```

However the `* print` command will print it to console but would not log it to html report as it is intended to be. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, hooks don't print to the HTML file when the entry point is a JS file.

Comment: `hooks.js` - you can try and see if this is something you can add to karate - and this is not a priority for me to fix. I really think in general the testing community cares more about pretty reports than actually doing the job of testing

Comment: @Raymond maybe you can try the new Java hooks introduced here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/855 - in the `ScenarioContext` you have access to a `Logger` instance.